# ReactJS Material UI Select throws warning with dynamic list source

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I tried searching for a similar issue but couldn't find anything.

Problem I have is with a simple dropdown 'pair' of properties, time and price.

'times' list starts as a pre-defined array (baseTimes) and then gets updated depending if the time was already used (servicesTimes)

```js
const baseTimes = [15, 30, 45, 60, 90];
const servicesTimes = []
const [times, setTimes] = useState(
    baseTimes.filter((a) => !servicesTimes.includes(a))
  ); // base service times not including already selected ones
```

THis all works and I get the dropdown as desired
[image]

When I add time/price pairs, the list on the right gets populated correctly too
[image]

So 'times' array gets smaller and smaller depending on how much services we add.

But, when times array becomes empty, I get a warning that I am switching from uncontrolled to controlled component.
[image]

This issue happens only with Select from @mui/material;

The NativeSelect doesn't throw an error but just looks ugly
[image]

But no error even when 'times' list becomes empty
[image]

Code for Select component:

```js
<FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ minWidth: 64 }}>
     <InputLabel>Time</InputLabel>
     <Select 
         value={time}
         onChange={(e) => {
            setTime(Number(e.target.value));
         }}
     >
     {times.map((t) => (
         <option key={t} value={t}>
             {t}
         </option>
     ))}
     </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Same code but for NativeSelect :

```js
<FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ minWidth: 64 }}>
    <InputLabel>Time</InputLabel>
    <NativeSelect
        value={time}
        onChange={(e) => {
            setTime(Number(e.target.value));
        }}
    >
    {times.map((t) => (
        <option key={t}>{t}</option>
    ))}
    </NativeSelect>
</FormControl>
```

Any suggestions how I can resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance for your efforts!